# Low quality question page not having same style as rest of site

Tags: bug, design, low-quality-posts

On Stack Overflow, when the "questions you ask per week is limited" page is shown, the style does not match the rest of the site.

It doesn't have the same heading and sidebar.

The entire webpage is in the image below

[image: You have a history of asking low quality questions. Please put more thought, time, and effort into your questions. To help you do this, the number of questions you may ask per week is currently limited. For more information, visit the Help Center.]

Update June 4 2019: I don't know if this problem exists anymore because I don't have my question amount limited anymore. Please tell me if this problem is still persisting.

Comment: We can't tell based on the partial screenshot. Can you please put full screenshot of the whole web page?

Comment: The screenshot is the full page.

Comment: We can't know that. Just press ALT+PrintScreen and paste it, it will give the actual whole window. Or at least also include the address bar so we get perspective.

Comment: I updated the screenshot