# How to reproduce low quality question page?

Tags: support, bug-reports

Recently I asked [Low quality question page not having same style as rest of site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311988/low-quality-question-page-not-having-same-style-as-rest-of-site) where I found a bug in the low quality question page.

Can I directly navigate to this page to test it?

Comment: I'm unaware of any route or trick to trigger that page to show. You need to get hired as a developer for SE to get that page at will ...